# Emulate android tablet of resolution1024 X 600

Tags: android, android-emulator

I wanted to emulate a tablet in my eclipse for android. How can I emulate a 600 X 1024 resolution tablet. Shall using the emulator WXGA 720 serve the same purpose?Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Under Create New AVD, you can specify the Resolution under skin

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For tablet is it 600X1024 or 1024 X 600?

Comment: 1024 X 600, you can flip the orientation if you need 600 x 1024 and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can select Window --> AVD Manager and then Select In AVD Manager as --> New / Edit --> Select Resolution and value as 1024 X 600.

Comment: You can select Resolution under the Skin and mentioned the screen size width and height.

Answer (score 0):

For changing resolution you have to open AVD manager in eclipse and

- Select the running Emulator
- Click on Edit
- AVD windows will open, then select option resolution
- Fill resolution you want example 600 * 1024